# AWS and secrets (Systems Manager, Secrets Manager, Key Management Service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-ssm, aws-secrets-manager

As AWS has now retired the KMS service it seems the Secrets Manager took over.

As it is quite costly there is also the Systems Manager parameter store.

None of these has audit capabilities as far as I see.

Does anybody know the roadmap or what to use for which use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [AWS Key Management Service (KMS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) is an encryption and key management service. It has **certainly *not* been retired**, and is used to manage encryption keys for services such as Amazon S3, Amazon EBS, Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift and Amazon EMR.

The [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) provides secure, hierarchical storage for configuration data management and secrets management. In fact, the Parameter Store uses AWS KMS to manage encryption keys.

The [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/secretsmanager/) makes it easier to manage secrets, including **automated password rotation** (in-built for Amazon RDS, or utilizing AWS Lambda for other systems).

*All* of these services provide **Auditing via [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html)**.

Comment: Thanks. Has the KMS still a UI? How is its name?

Comment: Look under IAM -> Encryption Keys, eg https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=eu-west-1#/encryptionKeys/us-east-1

Comment: Nice thank you. I only remember it being a dedicated service. This helped a lot!